# Why is my Connection String only working in Dev?

Tags: c#, security, app-config

See DGibbs answer below.

I can't have the config file saved with the EXE, as this is present on each user's desktop, so it seems I am unable to store the password in the config file and will have to come up with some other solution.

---

I have an app that needs to run a CMD command as an administrator. To achieve this, I stored the password in a connection string in app.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="mypw" connectionString="PASSWORD" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I am then able to call this in my `Cmd` class as a SecureString:

```
    private static SecureString pw()
            {
                string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mypw"].ConnectionString;
                SecureString ss = new SecureString();

                foreach (char c  in connectionString)
                {
                    ss.AppendChar(c);
                }

                return ss;
            }
```

When I run the app from VS on my machine with debugging (F5), it works fine and the password is retrieved. However, when running it in a development environment I see the exception `Object Reference not set to an instance of an object`, and from my own debugging I can see that this is happening at this line:

`string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mypw"].ConnectionString;`

Can anyone please explain why the app is able to retrieve the connection string on my machine but not when deployed elsewhere? Does the app.config file change when publishing the app?

Comment: Why are you using a connection string to store a password?

Comment: I'm not sure, I must have read somewhere a while ago that this was a done thing - is this not good practice?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494(v=VS.90).aspx

Comment: `Does the app.config file change when publishing the app` - Yes, there are transforms. Look for `app.Debug.config`. It's an XSLT file and might be removing your connection strings.

Comment: "Does the app.config file change when publishing the app?" Sorry, my crystal ball is under maintenance. Why don't you check this out yourself? *You* are the one with access to both your DEV and your Deploy environment.

Comment: Well the `<connectionStrings>` element is typically used to store database connection information...

Comment: @Bassie He's referring to this line from your OP: `"Does the app.config file change when publishing the app?"` Not the other poster.

Comment: I checked the App.config after publishing, but it looks exactly the same. If you guys suggest not storing the pw there, then I will change the code, but still interested to know why the deployed EXE can't find the connectionstring

Comment: @Bassie Try using `AppSettings` instead, retrieve it with something like `string pw = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["mypw"];`.

Comment: @DGibbs I added this to Settings.Settings as  connection string, but still seeing the same exception! I set Scope to Application, and used `ConfigurationManager.Appsettings`, as VS complained about `ConfigurationSettings` being obsolete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few things, don't use `<connectionStrings>`, this is typically used to store credentials for a db connection, it doesn't make sense here. Try using `AppSettings` within the `App.config` file e.g

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="mypw" value="password" />
</appSettings>
```

You can retrieve the value like this:

```
string pw = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["mypw"];
```

Finally, make sure you have the config file deployed, it should be `[ApplicationName].exe.config` and **not** `App.Config`. If it doesn't appear, check the `Copy to output directory` setting, make sure it's set to `Copy Always`.

Comment: Thank you for you answer DGibbs, but I think there must be something else at play here. I have updated my app.config with the appSettings tag as you explained ( I placed it at the bottom of the app.config file, but inside the `<configuration>` tag), but still seeing the same issue! This occurs when using `ConfigurationSettings` or `ConfigurationManater` - there doesn't seem to be a difference in the Exception

Comment: Did you check the `Copy to output directory` setting on the `App.config` file in your solution? Can you confirm that the `[AppName].exe.config` file is in the bin along with the .exe? Other than that, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: I have set `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy always`, and I can see `IT Self Help.exe.config` in `IT Self Help\bin\debug\` and it looks identical to the one in VS. However, when running the app in live, only the EXE file is copied onto the user's machine - the config file is left where it is. Would this make a difference?

Comment: The config should be in the same directory as the .exe

Comment: Okay thank you DGibbs - sorry for not knowing this and thanks for helping me. I guess my password will just have to be stored in the actual code of the application - it seems so wrong! I can't have a config file on the user's desktop.

Comment: No worries, happy to help